# Heroku build succeeded but failed to deploy

Tags: python, django, heroku, dockerfile

My Django website is running as expected on my machine but the Heroku logs saying `Python can't open file 'manage.py'` however my manage.py is working on my local machine. I'm running my Django project locally in a docker container.

Below is a screenshot of the Heroku log. How do I make Heroku find "manage.py"?
[image: heroku log]

Comment: Your `curl` command always fails because the command is not known. Does `manage.py` exist in the root directory of your git repository?

Comment: yes. I pushed it to GitHub and manage.py is there in Github.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the only way I see this error can happen is if `manage.py` is not in the root of your git repository, but a subfolder.

Comment: Thanks. You're correct, I in my dockerfile I had project/ as my root instead of /project/. I didn't notice it because it didn't affect mamage.py on my local machine. Thanks again